# Unwanted indentation in framed section headings in LaTex Exam

Tags: sectioning, positioning, indentation, exam, framed

I'm writing a document using Latex's Exam class where I'd like to make framed section headings, in order to reproduce a pre-existent document.

I was able to draw frames with titlesec package with the frame shape:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam} 
... 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} 
... 
\titleformat{\section}[frame] {\Large\bfseries} {} {0pt} {\centering #1} {}
```

Almost everything is fine but I noticed that section heading boxes are indentated, which is an unwanted behavior.

I manually moved the heading using `\hspace`. However, this solution worked for the first heading only, as you can check in the screenshot bellow (where I used `\geometry{showframe=true}` to enhance the issue):

[image: Screenshot of a PDF showing unwanted indentation of section heading frames.]

I tested several solutions, nothing worked. I'm open to use other methods to put the section in a box, such as `\fbox` or `\framebox`.

What could I do to remove section frame indentation? In the ideal case, all section boxes are left aligned with question and choices labels.

---

EDIT: I was finally able to produce a MWE. Notice the `\hspace{-7.5mm}` in every section -- a desperate attempt. But it works only on first:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=12mm, bottom=15mm, left=12mm, right=12mm]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=true}

% framed section headings
\titleformat{\section}[frame]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\centering #1}{}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}

% questions and choices desired customizations
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\large \textbf{\thequestion.}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\thechoice)}

\setlength\columnsep{7mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{questions}

            \hspace{-7.5mm}\section{A SECTION}
            
            \question Talvez seja interessante ter um enunciado suficientemente logo para ocupar mais de uma linha, quiçá três. Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Este é outro enunciado. Espera-se que seja a questão dois. Vamos colocar a resposta correta no segundo item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Vamos para mais uma questão, na qual o correto será o terceiro item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \hspace{-7.5mm}\section{ANOTHER SECTION}

            \question Talvez seja interessante ter um enunciado suficientemente logo para ocupar mais de uma linha, quiçá três. Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Este é outro enunciado. Espera-se que seja a questão dois. Vamos colocar a resposta correta no segundo item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Vamos para mais uma questão, na qual o correto será o terceiro item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \hspace{-7.5mm}\section{ONE MORE SECTION}

            \question Talvez seja interessante ter um enunciado suficientemente logo para ocupar mais de uma linha, quiçá três. Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Este é outro enunciado. Espera-se que seja a questão dois. Vamos colocar a resposta correta no segundo item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Vamos para mais uma questão, na qual o correto será o terceiro item.
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

            \question Escolha uma das opções. 
            \begin{choices}
                \choice Primeiro item.
                \choice Segundo item.
                \choice Terceiro item.
                \choice Quarto item.
            \end{choices}

        \end{questions}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Do you read the first error of the four errors reported by TeX? It is very important. Don't be surprised that the pdf output isn't as expected when there are errors.

Comment: Thank you @Mensch for the instruction. 

I found that `\hspace{}` works only on sections without `\question` before it. That's why I can control the first section indentation. But I can't control indentation on other sections yet. Any clue is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm back. I was able to solve this using `\usepackage{changepage}` and placing sections inside **adjustwidth** environment: `\begin{adjustwidth}{-18pt}{0pt}\section{A SECTION}\end{adjustwidth}`, where `{18pt}` and `{0}` are margin adjusts. It's not very elegant since I had to provide these adjusts manually. Thanks!